# What is this method of solving called and why does it work? (From WA)

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation, wolfram-alpha

Wolfram Alpha uses a scary-looking algebraic method to solve $x^{3}-x-1=0$ that I've never encountered before. It seems that every other online algebra calculator uses numerical methods, such as the Newton-Raphson method. As I don't have a premium subscription to WA, I cannot paste the step-by-step here, but I will painstakingly type out the main steps shown on the mobile app:

Solve for x over the real numbers:
$x^{3}-x-1=0$

Change coordinates by substituting $x=y+\frac{λ}{y}$, where $λ$ is a constant value that will be determined later: $-1-y-\frac{λ}{y}+\left(y+\frac{λ}{y}\right)^{3}=0$

Multiply both sides by $y^3$ and collect in terms of $y$:

$y^{6}+y^{4}\left(3λ-1\right)-y^{3}+y^{2}\left(3λ^{2}-λ\right)+λ^{3}=0$

Substitute $λ=\frac{1}{3}$ and then $z=y^{3}$, yielding a quadratic equation in the variable $z$:

$z^{2}-z+\frac{1}{27}=0$

Find the positive solution to the quadratic equation and substitute back for $z=y^{3}$:

$y^{3}=\frac{1}{18}\left(9+\sqrt{69}\right)$

Taking cube roots gives $\frac{\sqrt[3]{9+\sqrt{69}}}{\sqrt[3]{2}\cdot3^{\frac{2}{3}}}$ times the third roots of unity (I won't write them here), substitute each value of $y$ into $x=y+\frac{1}{3y}$, bring each solution to a common denominator and simplify:

$x=\frac{2\sqrt[3]{\frac{3}{\sqrt{69}+9}}+\sqrt[3]{2\left(\sqrt{69}+9\right)}}{6^{\frac{2}{3}}}$

OR $x=\frac{1}{6}\left(2\left(-3\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}\sqrt[3]{\frac{2}{\sqrt{69}+9}}-2^{\frac{2}{3}}\sqrt[3]{-3\left(\sqrt{69}+9\right)}\right)$

OR $x=\frac{1}{6}\left(\left(-2\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}\sqrt[3]{-3\left(\sqrt{69}+9\right)}-2\left(3\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}\sqrt[3]{\frac{-2}{\sqrt{69}+9}}\right)$

First of all, what is this "changing coordinates" sorcery and why does it work? Second, as Anakin Skywalker once asked, is it possible to learn this power (as a Grade 12 student with a little more math knowledge than average) and what can I search for to learn more about it?

P.S. None of the math teachers in my school know anything about it.

Comment: I might be wrong, but this seems like [Cardano's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Cardano's_formula)

Comment: You can definitely learn it.  That said, most mathematicians don't.  If you just need the numerical value of the root of a cubic, then numerical methods are faster than this (and  even with the closed formula you need numerical methods to approximate the square roots).  It is rare that you need the closed form solution for a general cubic and, if that need arises, you can always look the method up.  It's got a lot of steps but it is not complicated.

Comment: @angryavian I once taught myself Cardano's method but I never learnt about it like this. I've never seen anything like the second step.

Comment: In point of fact, Cardano's method is not all that hard to remember; the steps follow one another very naturally once the cubic is depressed and the substitution $x = u + v$ is made into $x^3 + ax + b = 0$.

Comment: @RobertLewis Yes, I have learned about depressing the cubic and I do actually like that method. I simply have never come across anything about changing coordinates or using variables whose values "will be determined later" while solving examples. Are you certain this is Cardano's method?

Comment: @Micah Windsor: This method is I think derived from Cardano's by combining several of the steps into one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments, this is Cardano's method, which is quite old (renaissance innovation!).

You have the equation $x^3 - x -1= 0$. In the Cardano method (which was geometrically inspired, I believe) you set $x = u+v$ and then impose a condition on the $u$ and $v$ to simplify to a quadratic. This will work as there is no quadratic term (if there is one, we do a linear change of variables to get rid of it first)

So $$(u+v)^3 - (u+v) - 1= 0$$ which simplifies to

$$0 = u^3 + 3u^2 v + 3u v^2 + v^3 - (u+v)-1 = u^3 + v^3 + 3uv(u+v)-(u+v) -1 $$

which implies $$u^3 + v^3 - 1 = 0\tag{1}$$ **if** we assume $$3uv=1\tag{2}$$ so that the middle mixed terms cancel out. But that last condition on $uv$ means that we know $u^3v^3$ too; cube the relation on both sides and we have

$$27u^3v^3=1 \tag{3}$$ so we're in a situation where if we set $a=u^3$, $b=v^3$, we know that $$a+b=1 \text{ and } ab = \frac{1}{27}$$

which reduces to a quadratic (!) equation in $a$ or $b$:

$$a + \frac{1}{27a} = 1 \implies a^2 + \frac{1}{27} = a \implies a^2 - a + \frac{1}{27}=0\tag{4}$$

Now solve $4$, so you know $a$ (two options, usually) and thus $u^3$ and $u$ and $b$ too, hence $v^3$ and $v$ too and then $x = u+v$ is the looked for solution.

Quite a nifty find by old Cardano, eh? Of course he had to do it in roman numerals for extra credit, and without modern notations.

The method you describe, setting $x = y + \lambda \frac{1}{y}$, is doing the two first steps at once: writing the solution as sum of two terms that have a constant (to be determined) product. Note that you get the exact same quadratic.

Comment: While I appreciate the response, I was not looking for an explanation of plain old Cardano's method that I could easily find with a quick Google search. I was hoping someone could explain the specific steps WA took. You didn't follow the same steps, so all I know is that this is indeed some exotic variation of Cardano's method.

Comment: @MicahWindsor If you look at the method you described, it does two steps of Cardano at once at the expense of a bit more computation (No problem for a computer, but the method I described is more human friendly).

Comment: "It does two steps of Cardano at once" How so? And where? And which two steps? I still have so many unanswered questions!

Comment: @MicahWindsor Look at the last paragraph I added: you write $x=u+v$ with $uv=\frac{1}{3}$ (which is your $\lambda$). Your substitution anticipates the fact that we'll want a constant product of $u$ and $v$. In fact you use $u=y$ $v=\frac{\lambda}{y}$ and reduce to an equation in $z=y^3$. Your $z$ is my $a$ etc. The methods are exactly the same.

Comment:  is equal to $\frac{1}{3}$, not $\frac{1}{27}$

Comment: @MicahWindsor true, but do you see mow that the method is exactly Cardano's in disguise?

Comment: Okay, I think I understand. Thank you for your time.